# Difficulties applying zyp.sen() to a RasterBrick object in R

Tags: r, regression

I have a RasterBrick object that represents a raster time series (say different images of the same scene over a thirty year period) and I'm trying to perform a Theil-Sen regression on this time series.

I'm attempting to do this through the zyp.sen() and calc() functions but I've run into a roadblock.

Here's what I've tried running:

```
 temp <- list()
 for(i in 1:10) {
     temp[[i]] <- runif(36,-1, 1)
     temp[[i]] <- matrix(temp[[i]], 6, 6)
     temp[[i]] <- raster(temp[[i]])}
 temp <- brick(temp)

 time <- 1:nlayers(temp)

 fun=function(x) { if (is.na(x[1])){ NA } else { m = zyp.sen(x~time)}}

 calc(temp,fun)
```

However, I keep running into this error:

```
Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
cannot use this function
```

And I'm not really sure why, or what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not entirely yours.  `zyp.sen` is not well written: it fails unless you guess correctly concerning the syntax it is hoping for.  (Whether that is its only problem is a question I have not pursued, but you might want to.)

One way to verify this conclusion is to *test* your function--which is a wise idea in any case, even when you are confident in the software you are using.

```
x <- rnorm(length(time))
fun(x)
```

**This fails.**  The error is

> Error in yy[1:(n - i)] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

A quick debugging session indicates the problem is in `zyp.sen` (a part of the `zyp` package), which attempts to index an array with the value `0-1`.

This behavior would be enough to make me look for a different package (or even write my own Theil-Sen regression, since it's easy to do).  But if you must use this particular one, here's a workaround.  It coddles `zyp.sen` to match precisely what it seems to be looking for: an *explicit* data frame argument and *explicit* naming of all variables in the formula.  I have had to modify your function, though, because it was doomed to failure anyway: you were attempting to return the entire Theil-Sen model and store it in the brick.  That would produce an error in any event.  You need to choose which part(s) of the model you want: the coefficients?  Just the slope?  Something else?  This example returns just the slope:

```
library(raster)
library(zyp)
fun <- function(y) { 
  if (any(is.na(y))){ 
    NA_real_ 
  } else { 
    X <- data.frame(y=y, time=time)
    model <- zyp.sen(y ~ time, X)
    beta.hat <- coef(model)
    beta.hat["time"]
  }
}
```